# Vertically and horizontally aligning childrens in parent divs

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a page in html , following is my main coding of div

```
<div class="wrapperCat">

    <div  id="all" class="categories">

          <img style="margin-top: 5px;" src="images/colored_livecha.png" alt="" width="100" height="41" />
          <label class="catText" >All Rings</label>

    </div>

    <div  id="pave" class="categories">

          <img style="margin-top: 5px;" src="images/colored_livecha.png" alt="" width="100" height="41" />
          <label class="catText" >Pave</label>

    </div>

    <div  id="vintage" class="categories">

          <img style="margin-top: 5px;" src="images/colored_livecha.png" alt="" width="100" height="41" />
          <label class="catText" >Vintage</label>

    </div>

    <div  id="contemp" class="categories">

          <img style="margin-top: 5px;" src="images/colored_livecha.png" alt="" width="100" height="41" />
          <label class="catText" >Contemporary</label>

    </div>
</div>
```

The classes are defined as

```
.categories{  
    margin: 10px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 159px; 
    background: url("../images/main_cat_bg~iPad.png");
}

.wrapperCat{
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    background: url("../images/background~iPad.png");
}

.catText{

    bottom: 0;
    color: #701344;
    font-size: 16px; 
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center; 
}
```

The output result is as follow

[image]

What I actually want are following things:

1. Let's say, We have first box, The image and text. *I want them to be "Horizontally align in the center".*
2. I want all the divs with class category to show horizontally in the main wrapper div.

e.g

if i have 8 children in the main div they would show as

```
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8
```

How can I change the css to achieve the above two things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add:

```
display:inline-block;
text-align:center;
```

To your `.categories` class

Comment: that worked well , just one thing left, is there a possible way, i can put margin bottom to text and margin top to image instead of using <br />. The live chat image and text. Also with inline block if i want to show them horizontally center to give equal spacing on both left and right sides

Answer (score 0):

My first attempt if I understand your question:

Insert `<br />` after each image, and make `.categories` styled with `text-align: center;` and `display: inline-block`. You may want to throw some margin also to separate each category block.

> ```
> .categories{  
>     margin: 10px;
>     width: 150px;
>     height: 159px; 
>     background: url("../images/main_cat_bg~iPad.png");
>     display: inline-block;
>     margin: 5px 5px;
> }
> ...
> <div  id="all" class="categories">
>     <img style="margin-top: 5px;" src="images/colored_livecha.png" alt="" width="100" height="41" /><br />
>     <label class="catText" >All Rings</label>
> </div>
> ```

Let me know if this was what you wanted, and if not, explain further and I'll try my best. Good luck!

Comment: i did use display:inline-block;
text-align:center; and it works good , is there a possible way, i can put margin bottom to text and margin top to image instead of using <br />. The live chat image and text. Also with inline block if i want to show them horizontally center to give equal spacing on both left and right sides

Comment: Add `text-align:center` to `wrapperCat` to center the blocks.
To vertically center image and text inside each block, you should display the block as `table-cell`, but would also need another block to be a parent displayed as `table`. Or else, use tricks to margin-top 50% and -50%. I'm a little busy now, later on I'll provide an example.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the

```
.categories{  
    margin: 10px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 159px; 
    background: url("../images/main_cat_bg~iPad.png") center;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
}
```

hope you will find the result by this updation